# Adding MOQ to a .NET 4.0 project is not possible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, moq

I want to add MOQ .net library to a .NET 4.0 project. I get an error message that I should convert the project to something smaller than 4.0. I need to use .NET 4.0 also because of other project dependencies.

How can I make MOQ work with a .NET 4.0 project in VS2010 ?

Comment: I am using Moq in a .Net 4.0 project without any problem. Maybe it's the version you are using. I am using this link: from google code: http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/detail?name=Moq.4.0.10827.Final.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Make sure you have NuGet package manager installed (Tools/Extension Manager).
- Right click on Solution Explorer/References, choose Manage NuGet Packages.
- Type Moq in the search box.
- Install and enjoy.

Comment: After clicking `Manage NuGet Packages`, you might need to click on the `Manage` button to install.. (I am referring to VS2012)

Comment: I use VS 2013 and I have several projects in my solution and a test project. 
When I choose the moq package in the nuget package manager it shows me an option window with checkboxes for every project. Do I have to install the moq package in every project or just in the test project?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to. I think I had that with VS2013 when it was a pre-release version of the package.   No problem with the latest version of NuGet in VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version from Google Code (http://code.google.com/p/moq/), works in a .Net 4.0 project. I would just download the dll again.

Here is the download link: http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/detail?name=Moq.4.0.10827.Final.zip

The zip file at that location contains a .Net 4 folder. Use the dll : Moq.dll from the NET40 folder and everthing will work fine. Just do a normal Add Reference on the project.

I would check the version number and the Runtime veseion of the assembly you are trying to use. It should say:

Runtime Version: v4.0.20926

Version: 4.0.10827.0

Comment: It's much easier to use NuGet as explained by @Phil

Comment: @TimLong via NuGet you cannot to install, because there only 4.5 and upper

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, it may be worth pointing out that it is also possible to use the Visual Studio command line package manager tool:

1) **Open the console in VS**

View >> Other Windows >> Package Manager Console

2) **Install Moq**

Type `Install-Package Moq` at the prompt

Note: If your tests are in a separate project, make sure that you select that project in the project dropdown.

This will install the latest package available in NuGet, which should address your compatibility issue. See http://nuget.org/packages/moq.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out that you're using .NET 4, rather than the .NET 4 Client Profile as your Target Framework. I had the same issue and that was the cause for me.